# How to determine if checkbox is checked using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I am getting `Notice: Undefined variable: myvariable` when I post my form with the checkbox unchecked.

I need to check if the checkbox is not checked.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create hidden field before checkbox with same name on html form.

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="check"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check"/>
```

In this case the value $_POST['check'] is defined always

Comment: To clarify, in your example, $_POST['check'] would be defined; not $_POST['checkbox'].

Answer (score 4):

The `isset` function will tell you if a variable, key in an array, or a public property in an object exists:

```
if (isset($variable)) {...
if (isset($array['key'])) {...
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's coming up as undefined, then do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['myvariable'])){
    //this means it's checked... do something with it
}else{
    //this means it's not checked.. do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A common approach is to default it to *some value* (i.e. `false`) if it is not set by the form submission (i.e. `$_POST`). The following uses a ternary operator, adjust the values to your liking:

```
 $checkbox_value = isset($_POST['myvariable']) ? $_POST['myvariable'] : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST["foo"])) {
    //Do something...
}
```